# Cordova - Android - Notification and icon when getting location

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation

I am making an Ionic App where I use the [cordova geolocation plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation). In Android 8 only, I am getting a notification with an icon which isn’t the icon of my App. Is it possible to change this icon and the texts or remove the notification?

I am calling the method to get my position like this:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 1000, maximumAge: 1000 }).then(...
```

And this is the icon I am talking about (the one about fusedlocationprovider):

https://sjc1.discourse-cdn.com/ionicframework/uploads/default/original/3X/e/4/e42576b221bd6c9aef4c124e297e0b1eaf626d5a.jpeg

Is there any way to do this? I guess it is something I can configure in config.xml most probably but can't find out what it is.

Thanks!